# distinguishing between openni_tracker broadcasts based on which user's information is being sent

Tags: ros, openi-tracker, transform-broadcaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am making a node that receives transforms from openni_tracker. Is there a way to make my node distinguish between transforms being sent for User 1, User 2, etc...?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10630/distinguishing-between-openni_tracker-broadcasts-based-on-which-user%27s-information-is-being-sent/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-29**:
If editing the ROS source code is a bad idea, do you have any other suggestions for solving this problem?

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-29**:
I am running the latest version of diamondback. How do I even install electric-turtle? When I went to the installation page, diamondback was the only option it gave me.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-28**:
"Anyways, I am running the latest version of ROS" By which you mean latest diamondback version?  latest electric-turtle version? latest unstable trunk head version?

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-28**:
If you wanted mainting the change as ROS got updated, you'd have to: 1) be certain that your change doesn't cause unforeseen consequences 1) continually make sure it worked with future versions.  2) be ok with your software only working with your custom verson of ROS

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-28**:
Also, what kind of maintenance problems would there be? It seems like it would be a pretty small change, but I guess I do not know what the effects of it would be.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-28**:
The lines that my version is missing have no pertinence to this question. It was just something that I noticed while looking at Bemfica's answer. Anyways, I am running the latest version of ROS.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-28**:
It would generally be a bad idea because it would be a maintenance nightmare for you. It would probably be much easier/better to just upgrade to the latest version of ROS since tfoote suggested it has the feature you're looking for.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-28**:
Would editing the openni_tracker.cpp file to send an index with each transform to specify which user's data is being sent be fine? Or is it a bad idea to edit ROS code? I know that it is supposed to be read-only.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-18**:
I tried to improve your title, but not sure if I interpreted you correctly. Please look at it and correct it if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The users transforms are all published as you can see on the [API](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/openni_tracker/html/openni__tracker_8cpp_source.html#l00096). You could write a subscriber to read it. But something makes me think that there is an easier way to do it.

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-19**:
I downloaded diamondback just under a month ago. The differences are not so important to me though.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-19**:
What version have you downloaded?  The online docs are generated from the newest version.  Which suggests that this feature will be in the next release.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-18**:
I just noticed that the code in your link is different from that of openni_tracker.cpp, the file that I got from downloading ROS. openni_tracker.cpp is missing lines 77, 78, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, and 91. Also, lines 82 and 93 are slightly different.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-18**:
I already have it set up to receive the transforms. My problem is that I am not sure how to differentiate between the head for User 1, the head for User 2, the head for User 3, etc...